# JavaScript: Fetch URL from JSON File and execute it in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to fetch JSON from URL using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/file.php', function(data) {
    //data
});
```

Example JSON: `{ "url":"http://example.com/execute.php" }`

Then I want to execute the URL in background (client side and without telling to user) which we have got from JSON file. 
And Repeat the whole process every second! Getting the JSON every second and executing in background and so on..

Comment: I highly doubt you want to do it every second.... So what is your issue? setTimeout is what you need....

Comment: What do you mean by executing the URL? You just want to keep calling the url you got in result?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute" the URL? You can't run PHP code client side since it's a server side language.

Comment: @BrianGlaz I just want to fetch that URL from user's IP, i don't want to get data from it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function callPhpFile() {

  $.ajax({
  file: "http://yoururl.com/executethis/script.php"
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() { callPhpFile() }, 1000);
  }});

}

setTimeout(function() { callPhpFile() }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Then I want to execute the URL in background (client side and without telling to user) which we have got from JSON file.

You don't need AJAX for a response, you can use it as a request as well. This will just run the PHP page every * times you call it. In the success listener you can do nothing, or implement a `setInterval()` to repeat the process

DOCS: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Can you please provide whole snippet? Because i'm not good at javascript!

Comment: @SukhchainSingh if this works, please accept the answer when possible.

Comment: interval is a BAD BAD thing to use here. If calls hang up you will have multiple open at the same time. Code should either wait until call is done to fire off next or abort open calls when you make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i made for this solution, getting URL every second and executing it!

```
function getURL() {
    var url = 'http://example.com/pending.php';
    $.getJSON(url, function(result){
        var executeL = result.url;
        $.get(executeL);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(getURL, 1000);
    getURL();
});
```